# Can I use SAPI 4 on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, text-to-speech, sapi

The problem with SAPI 5 is that I can't find any free Portuguese (Brazilian) voices; plus, I need to distribute the speech engine along with my program, so the paid alternatives would be way too much expensive.

Is there any way that I can use and distribute the SAPI 4 engine and voices and make it work in Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Comment: You are not allowed to re-distribute SAPI.  Installing it anyway is very likely to destroy the OS configuration, disabling all other programs that use SAPI.

Comment: You *are* allowed to redistribute SAPI; Microsoft makes redistributable merge modules that you can include in your install module.  

Your larger point is still valid, however; installing SAPI 4 on Windows 7 will not work, and might corrupt the SAPI 5.3 installation already present.

Answer (score 3):

SAPI4 works on Windows 7 and Vista.  MS Agent, which depends on SAPI4, now is supported on Win 7.  If you install MS Agent, SAPI4 should work.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969168